# Use swap partition for hibernation

Tags: usb, hibernate, swap

I just created a swap partition out of my useless USB drive (4GB). I'm successfully using it, it shows in the `top` command and I also edited the `etc/fstab` to automatically mount it at startup.

My problem is, while switching on my computer, I see this message with all the text **Hibernation: resume: no device specified**

What should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type:

`sudo blkid`

This will list all your connected devices. Look for your USB drive containing your swap space. There will be a UUID="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" entry (universally unique identifier for a device). Note the number between the quotes "".

Now type

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Search for a line that begins with

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`

and enter after the =

`"resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"`

*with the quotes!* The Xs represent the number you noted after typing `blkid`, insert them instead of the Xs. If there already is an entry of some kind, be sure to *include it in between the quotes*, too.

(For example, your line might look like this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs resume=UUID=0258cebf-0906-4b1b-af15-abb35862f180"`

**But do not simply copy and paste this, yours should look different!**)

Save and close the file and type

`sudo update-grub`

This will take a small time. After it's finished, reboot. You should be all set now.